# Cython compiling error: Saying that Array is a Struct

Tags: cython, cythonize

This is a minimally reproducible version of my Cython error. The code runs in C++.

The compiler is telling me error C2088 that "+= is illegal for struct". However, it is being passed an array.

The pyx file:

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint32_t as Card
from cpython cimport array
import array

cdef extern from "ace_eval.h":
    void ACE_addcard(h, Card c)

def create_hand():
    cdef array.array h = array.array('I',[0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    ACE_addcard(h, 257)

    return h
```

The function imported from the header is:

```
#define ACE_addcard(h,c)  h[c&7]+=c,h[3]|=c
```

I have also tried declaring my arrays using 
`cdef Card h[5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array.array` is a Python object that is ultimately compiled into a struct (so this is what C++ sees). Element access to it is controlled at a Python level by `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, which are compiled by Cython into C API function calls. When Cython sees code for an array being manipulated it'll generate the appropriate C API function calls. You code using C++ `#define` statements attempts to manipulate it at C++ compile time and prevents Cython from knowing what's going on.

Ideally you should be using "typed memoryviews" which give Cython quicker access to the array (but will *still* not work with the C++ `#define` since this is applied after Cython has processed the file):

```
cdef int[::1] h = array.array('I',[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) # you may have to change the type long... I haven't tested it

h[257&7]+=257
h[3]|=257
```

If you absolutely insist on using macros instead then they need to take something with a C++ array interface. A pointer is probably the easiest option and can be got from:

```
cdef int* h_ptr = &h[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out tonight. I think I need to change my thinking from just connecting to C to putting more of the code in Cython. Do you think that's a good general approach?

Comment: I'd definitely 100% avoid mixing macros and Cython if you can - that's a recipe for confusion. There's no problem with connecting to C if the code already exists and is useful though - it does mean you have to use Cython at "pointer level" which removes some of the nice Pythony advantages

Comment: The first way worked. The second way didn't. I'm still not able to generate an array in Cython and send to C for consumption there. It would be nice to be able to - there are some more complex functions I'd like to leave in C. And those also take arrays as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

@DavidW 's second way of

```
    cdef Card h[5]
    h[:] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    cdef Card* h_ptr = &h[0]
```

also worked once I also adjusted my cdef like so to accept the pointer. Note that the function in the #define macro is not changed and does not have return type specified.

```
cdef extern from "ace_eval.h":
       void ACE_addcard(Card* h, Card c)
```

This allowed me to pass any of my arrays over flawlessly.

This is actually what it says in the docs, but it was a bit obtuse to me - hopefully my explanation helps someone else. 
https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html

> If the header file defines a function using a macro, declare it as though it were an ordinary function, with appropriate argument and result types.

Comment: If you don't specify the argument type then it's assumed to be a Python object (which an `array.array` is, but a pointer isn't). One other option is to use the C varargs syntax `void ACE_addcard(...)` in which case Cython won't try to check the argument types (and then it's up to C to see if it compiles)